# How do I deploy TinyMCE MVC Project on a Shared Server or Plesk Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce, plesk

I have been able to setup the TinyMCE MVC plugin in my MVC project and all works fine on my development server.

But Immediately I moved the application to the deployment server (Plesk Shared Hosting), the TinyMCE Plugin refuses to show up.

Please what do I do? Should I copy the content of the Packages folder to the server or what are the required files and where do I deploy them?
The Server is a Plesk Hosting Server to be specific.

Note:
All other functionalities works fine only the plugin refuses to show.
I have also tried checking if maybe it throws a JS exception, using the F12 Developer tools across all browsers but nothing is coming up.

Thank you as you gladly help me.

Comment: Are you 100% certain the tinymce files have made it to your development server?

Comment: Also, can we see the code where you initialize TinyMCE?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky I am certain the files made it to the deployment server, though I am a bit confused if I should move the files in the packages folder along as well. Though I don't understand what you mean by the initialization CODE because I installed it using Nuget and it works fine on my development server/system but doesn't come up on deployment to a shared hosting server.

Comment: You shouldn't have to move it anywhere (packages folder).

Comment: Any javascript errors in the developers console when running it live?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky, no Javascript Error, I used the Tinymce.mvc.jquery version for one of my projects and it didn't work and when I used Tinymce.mvc for another project it worked and it comes up even in deployment. I guess I will just try revert it to the tinymce.mvc and see what works. And also for the one that worked I also updated the Json.net from Newtosoft.Json to 8.0.2 from Nuget. Let me do the same to the other project and see if it works. I will let U know. And thanks for your time

Comment: There's something else going on here.  I'd suggest removing the TinyMCE.Mvc esque packages, and only install TinyMCE from NuGet.  You'll get a tinymce folder inside your script folders.  Then, on the page with your textarea, initialize TinyMCE and point it to that textarea, and see what happens.